# Play mp3 file from raw resource on click of a TextView

Tags: android, mp3, listener, media-player

I want to play a certain mp3 file when a text is clicked. For example, I clicked the word "Nicholas", the app have to play nicholas.mp3.

Sorry for my messy code, I'm new to android dev:

```
package com.example.playword;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
//import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
//import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PlayWord extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        //final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
         
        final TextView nicholas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nicholas);
        final TextView was = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.was);
        
        nicholas.setText("Nicholas ");
        was.setText("was ");        
        
        /*
        Button btn = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.nicholasBtn));
        
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                nicholas.setText("Nicholas (Clicked!) ");
            }

          });
        */
        
        View.OnClickListener handler = new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.nicholas: // doStuff
                        
                        MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(null, R.raw.aaanicholas);
                        
                        try {
                            mPlayer.prepare();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        
                        mPlayer.start();
                        
                        nicholas.setText("Nicholas (Clicked!) ");
                        break;
                        
                    case R.id.was: // doStuff
                        
                        MediaPlayer mPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(null, R.raw.aaawas);
                        
                        try {
                            mPlayer1.prepare();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        
                        mPlayer1.start();
                        
                        was.setText("was (Clicked!) ");
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        findViewById(R.id.nicholas).setOnClickListener(handler);
        findViewById(R.id.was).setOnClickListener(handler);
        
    }
}
```

When I run this, I'm getting a force close error. Do you have a much better idea on this?

Comment: Just to add, Also try and implement AudioFocus https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You need to pass in a context instance into [MediaPlayer.create](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context,%20int)) method:

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(PlayWorld.this, R.raw.aaanicholas);
```

Also, after the `create()` call, prepare is already executed, so you don't need to execute it explicitly, just invoke `start()` right after `create()`.

Answer (score 3):

When you create the `mPlayer` object you should pass it the Context, which is in your case `PlayWord.this`.

Answer (score 2):

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(FakeCallScreen.this, R.raw.mysoundfile);
    mPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Please avoid giving code-only answers. Try to explain how your code solves OP's problem. It is more helpful to everyone, especially those less experienced than you, if you can provide some context and exposition.

Answer (score 2):

```
val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.music)
mediaPlayer.isLooping=true
mediaPlayer.start()
music_on_off_button.setOnClickListener {
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
        mediaPlayer.pause()
    } else {
            mediaPlayer.start()
    }
}
```

You can detect weather the music is playing or not by using isPlaying() method