# How to play an web streaming .mp3 file in Webview(android)

Tags: android, webview, streaming, mp3

So I need to play an audio which streaming on the internet. For my android app. I am using webview but can't figure out how to do it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to enable the plugins for the webview, like this :

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView01);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

// Added in API level 8
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
```

[Android Documentation WebSettings.PluginState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.PluginState.html)

But it might be better to use native player see below:

- [Streaming Audio from A URL in Android using MediaPlayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965784/streaming-audio-from-a-url-in-android-using-mediaplayer)

**Android Supported Media Formats:** http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

---

(offline media player related links)

- http://www.hrupin.com/2010/12/simple-android-mp3-media-player
- http://android-er.blogspot.gr/2010/07/play-mp3-in-sd-card-using-androids.html
- [Android: Play mp3 file from raw resource on click of a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466882/android-play-mp3-file-from-raw-resource-on-click-of-a-textview)

Comment: It is not a URL exactly. The music is streamed on a flash player on the streaming website. I will somehow extract mp3 from that flash and play it in webview. You know how I can do that?

Comment: have you tested any of the suggested?

Comment: it depends on the site / radio / streaming mechanism and it is not always possible to stream the extracted url on android. see added url for Android Supported Media Formats

Comment: The flash player is flash based(obviously) but I think the audio its streaming is mp3.. Can that mp3 be extracted and played? Is this possible by any method?

Comment: programmatically is quite impossible... get through html-source-code and try to find the url.

Comment: OK, I got the mp3's url through the html source code. It looks like this(but not this, mine is a live stream): http://www.whatisthatsong.net/charts-lists/charts%20and%20lists-mp3/classic%20rock/37.%20Pink%20Floyd%20-%20Comfortably%20Numb.mp3 . Can this be played in android? I tried after enabling the plugins you said to earlier, but the webview now doesn't even open the page, it just shows a white screen. It's working fine with google.com. How can I get it to play? Thanks!

Comment: Try the url with the media player!

Answer (score 3):

// Added in API level 8
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

This method was deprecated in API level 18.
Plugins will not be supported in future, and should not be used.