# can not play mp3 file from raw folder in android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer

I created raw folder inside res directory and inserted mp3 file.I try to play my mp3 file with mediaplayer.
this is a my source -

```
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.music_1);
 mediaPlayer.start();
```

but when I run app I have exception.this is a my logcat exception -

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
```

How I can solve my problem?
If anyone knows solution,please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question has already an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5466930/1872157

Comment: @SachinThampan Thampan i did not understood it.can you show me right source?

Answer (score 0):

The exception `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference` of course means that you are trying to call the `start()` method on a `MediaPlayer` object that is null.

This of course means that the call `MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.music_1);` has returned `null`.

Possible reasons for that are

- `MainActivity.this` does not represent a valid [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) at the point of your code where you have this call
- `R.raw.music_1` does not actually point to any file
- The MP3 file in your `...res/raw/` folder is corrupted
- The MP3 file in your `...res/raw/` folder is not in [a supported format](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)